# Why compiler doesn't give me error when i try to read a private field?

Tags: java

I have a class

```
class Box {
    private double width;
    private double height;
    private double depth;

    Box(Box ob) {
        width = ob.width;
        height = ob.height;
        depth = ob.depth;
    }
}
```

**this class was compiled**. But i'm stack - **why?!** I have a private fields!
 **Why i have access to private fields**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [this tutorial page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html):

> The `private` modifier specifies that the member can only be accessed in its own class.

And you're accessing the field in the same class `Box`.

Comment: Thank you) I forget for this :D

Comment: I accept your answer at 10 minutes. Stackoverflow disallow me this now :(

Answer (score 2):

Private doesn't mean only the **object** can access its private members, it means the **class** can. So in your case, any object of the `Box` class can access all private members of any other `Box` object as long as it has a reference to it.

Answer (score 0):

Because these private field are only hidden to the outer world - that means to the outside of the class. At this class from any non static member (that is non-static method, initialization block or constructor) these are accessible directly

And for accessing these (non `static`) private member from a static method inside the `Box` class you have to create an instance of the box class and after using getter method you can access them.

```
public static void methodInsideBox(){
   Box b = new Box(Box b);
   //using getter method
   double width = getWidth(b);
}
```